# Leaving a blank in a formula square on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a very basic spreadsheet and a formula in cell E1     =(D1- C1 )

If the values are not put in, the formula in E1 is coming up as 0.0

How can I get this to show up as a blank if I do not input data in to D1 or C1 cells

Comment: Look into `IF()`

Comment: Do you have something I can put in to the cell? I have tried to research but it's all very new to me

Comment: Since you want to display nothing if `D1` **or** `C1` is empty, you could try: `=IF(COUNT(C1:D1)=2,D1-C1,"")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply try-

```
=IF(D1-C1=0,"",D1-C1)
```

Comment: it came up as FALSE